# Python: More efficient way to break down string and append it to a list

Tags: python, string, list

I've been using something like this to take a string and break it down to add to a list

```
example_string = "Test"
example_list =[]
for x in example_string:
    example_list.append(x)
```

Output:

```
example_list = ['T','e','s','t']
```

Is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something better than :

```
example_string = "Test"
example_list = list(example_string)
```

Ouput :

```
example_list = ["T","e","s","t"]
```

In python strings are iterable like list or tuples, you can easily transform a string into a tuple or a list by calling `tuple()` or `list()` on it.

Comment: >.> Wow! I didn't even think about explicitly converting it! That's much more code efficient. But say if I wanted 3 letters per list item could I format it to do so?

Comment: It doesn't matter, more of a point of curiosity, but if I use double quotes in my initial string, I still end up getting *single* quotes with the list .. are you sure your output as shown contains double quotes?

Comment: @Levon I think he just made that up without running it in a terminal. 
Also I just wanted to say that calling `tuple()` on a string would be pretty pointless!

Comment: @Levon : right, I didn't copy/paste the output from my console, I copy/paste it from the OP question, I obtain single quotes too.

Comment: @Cédric Julien - Yes, sorry I simple have a preference to double quotes and didn't run it in a interpreter. Levon - Yes you should get single quotes I believe that's Python's default

Comment: I'll delete my solution since it's identical .. must have come in 20 seconds late :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group 3 letters per list item (as per your comment on @Cedric's answer), then this is the `grouper` recipe from the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

(You will need to import the `izip_longest` function from `itertools`.)

Comment: @ Li-aung - Just checking cause I don't have a computer with python around me, but intetools is a default module in 2.x is it not?

Comment: Correct. `itertools` is a base module of Python.

Answer (score 0):

To group into groups of N (without external modules), you can use the recipe in [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) of `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`

So:

```
>>> list(zip(*[iter("longerstring")]*3))
[('l', 'o', 'n'), ('g', 'e', 'r'), ('s', 't', 'r'), ('i', 'n', 'g')]
```